# React Redux problem on dispatching on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a button that dispatches an action to create a post, for some reason the request never proceeds and it fails. This is the action. I have constants that's why types is not on a string

```
export const createPost = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_CREATE_REQUEST,
    });
    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: POST_CREATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    // if (message === 'Not authorized, token failed') {
    //   dispatch(logout());
    // }
    dispatch({
      type: POST_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};
```

It continues to the POST_CREATE_REQUEST but always errors out to the POST_CREATE_FAIL.

I tried using postman and it works fine, I think the problem is the createPost action can't seem to receive the token even though im logged in as an admin, I'm not sure.

This is the useSelector of the postCreate

```
  const postCreate = useSelector(state => state.postCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    post: createdPost,
  } = postCreate;
```

and this is the useSelector of the user that is logged in, currently as an admin.

```
  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
```

Comment: And what is the `error` that is caught, it will probably help you.

Comment: gives me an error 401 which is weird because im currently logged in as an admin.

Comment: Did you check the value of "userInfo"? Is it returning the token?

Comment: Yes, since it works on all other function and dispatch that requires the token, only the createPost doesn't work.

Comment: Try this for sending the request:

const token = '..your token..'

await axios.post(url, {
  //...data
}, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  }
})

Comment: Still didn't work...

Comment: what you get in the catch error? any error in the try block will go to catch. Please provide the screenshot of that error

Comment: Debugging steps I think you should take (*if you haven't already*): **(1)** Verify your request is correct. Is the `Authorization` header what you expect it to be? Is the `token` being picked out of state? **(2)** If the request is correct then check our endpoint. How is it processing requests? Please also share exactly what the error is that is being caught in your frontend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already values on my Controller at the backend and just needed to add brackets in the action

from this

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`,
      config
    );
```

to this

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`, {},
      config
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this code

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`,
      config
    );
```

as

```
 const res = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`,
      config
    );
const data = res && res.data
```

Comment: Didn't work, as stated above it gives me an error because the app thinks I'm not  logged in and not receiving the token as it should be.

Comment: Try to use authorization token in this way: 

const token = '..your token..'

axios.post(url, {
  //...data
}, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  }
})